# Specify mapping expression - so that it works with LINQ EF and Projection

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a lot of code like this:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<DbModel.Kabinetas, Kabinetas>()
                .ForMember(n => n.Numeris, m => m.MapFrom(f => f.Numeris ?? ""))
                .ForMember(m => m.MetaDuomenys, y => y.MapFrom(s =>
                    new MetaDuomenys
                    {
                        ArPanaikintas = s.SecLevel == null ? (bool?)null : s.SecLevel == 2 ? true : false,
                        PakeitimuData = s.PakeitimuData
                    }))
                ;


            Mapper.CreateMap<DbModel.Specialybe, Specialybe>()
                .ForMember(i => i.Istaigos, y => y.Ignore())
               .ForMember(m => m.MetaDuomenys, y => y.MapFrom(s =>
                    new MetaDuomenys
                    {
                        ArPanaikintas = s.SecLevel == null ? (bool?)null : s.SecLevel == 2 ? true : false,
                        PakeitimuData = s.PakeitimuData
                    }))
                ;
```

Where the part wtih "MetaDuomenys" (a.k.a. MetaData) repeats it self over and over again..

I was hoping to be able to write something like this:

```
    Expression<Func<BaseWMeta, MetaDuomenys>> expr = p =>
                new MetaDuomenys
                {
                    ArPanaikintas = p.SecLevel == null ? (bool?)null : p.SecLevel == 2 ? true : false,
                    PakeitimuData = p.PakeitimuData
                };

Mapper.CreateMap<Expression<Func<BaseWMeta, MetaDuomenys>>, MetaDuomenys>();
```

and then use it like this:

```
 .ForMember(m => m.MetaDuomenys, y => y.MapFrom(s => expr))
```

So this kinda works, when I need a single object from the database, but if I try to project it like:

```
   db.Kabinetai.Project().To<KabinetasDC>()
```

I get exceptions like:

```
<m:internalexception>
<m:message>
The LINQ expression node type 'Lambda' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
</m:message>
<m:type>System.NotSupportedException</m:type>
```

Comment: The general consensus on SO is to not include tags in the title of questions fyi

Comment: ok, thanx, will keep in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ProjectUsing:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BaseWMeta, MetaDuomenys>()
    .ProjectUsing(p =>
            new MetaDuomenys
            {
                ArPanaikintas = p.SecLevel == null ? (bool?)null : p.SecLevel == 2 ? true : false,
                PakeitimuData = p.PakeitimuData
            });
```

ProjectUsing is like [ConvertUsing](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters) (defining the mapping between 2 types w/ a Func) except you get an Expression instead just a Func. This Expression is then passed to the Select projection any time AutoMapper finds the source/destination types for a custom projection.

The rest of your config is:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DbModel.Kabinetas, Kabinetas>()
    .ForMember(n => n.Numeris, m => m.MapFrom(f => f.Numeris ?? ""));
Mapper.CreateMap<DbModel.Specialybe, Specialybe>()
    .ForMember(i => i.Istaigos, y => y.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ValueResolver<TSource, TDestination>` ?

A simple example (string id to mongodb objectid):

```
public class UserIdResolver : ValueResolver<UserViewModel, ObjectId>
{
    protected override ObjectId ResolveCore(UserViewModel source)
    {
        ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source.Id))
        {
            objectId = new ObjectId(source.Id);
        }

        return objectId;
    }
}
```

And the mapping goes like this:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<UserViewModel, UserEntity>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, src => src.ResolveUsing<UserIdResolver>());
```

Comment: ah okay. you didn't mention about projection in initial post.

Comment: Yup.. sorry about that

Comment: it is kinda sad that this answer is downvoted. Initial question was way different from the current one.